# How to convert JSON to XML in objective C?

Tags: iphone, xml, json

I am using JSON converter to convert a XML string to JSON string. I need to convert this JSON string again back to XML string. Is there any specific methods to do this?

Answer (score 2):

With this code you can convert **JSON** to **NSDictionary**

```
NSString * jsonString = @"blblblblblb";
NSStringEncoding  encoding;
NSData * jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:encoding];
NSError * error=nil;
NSDictionary * parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Please use below code for converting NSDictionary to XML. So you can have JSON to XML converter.

```
+(NSString*)ConvertDictionarytoXML:(NSDictionary*)dictionary withStartElement:(NSString*)startele
{
    NSMutableString *xml = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    NSArray *arr = [dictionary allKeys];
    [xml appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
    [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",startele]];
    for(int i=0;i<[arr count];i++)
    {
        id nodeValue = [dictionary objectForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];
        if([nodeValue isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] )
        {
            if([nodeValue count]>0){
                for(int j=0;j<[nodeValue count];j++)
                {
                    id value = [nodeValue objectAtIndex:j];
                    if([ value isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                    {       
                        [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
                        [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[value objectForKey:@"text"]]];
                        [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        else if([nodeValue isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
            if([[nodeValue objectForKey:@"Id"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nodeValue objectForKey:@"Id"]]]; 
            else
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[nodeValue objectForKey:@"Id"] objectForKey:@"text"]]]; 
            [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }

        else
        {
            if([nodeValue length]>0){
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:[arr objectAtIndex:i]]]]; 
                [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",[arr objectAtIndex:i]]];
            }
        }
    }

    [xml appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</%@>",startele]];
    NSString *finalxml=[xml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
//  NSLog(@"%@",xml);
    return finalxml;
}
```